# Can a string be escaped via user input?

Tags: php, security, escaping, concatenation, fopen

Take this example code:

```
$data = $_POST["data"];
$file = $_POST["file"];
$filename = $file. ".txt";          # <-- can this .txt be escaped? maybe not in PHP, but even by the file system
$file = fopen($filename, "a");
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Nothing here is being sanitized and the user has full permission over the filename but not the extension. The `a` flag in `fopen` will look to create a file or write to the end of a file only.

If we switched this around and made it so the `$file` was specified with the extension, the user has full control to I/O on the server.

```
$filename = $file;                # /.ssh/id_rsa
...
fwrite($data);                    # New RSA key
```

So by specifying the extension this prevents much malicious things in this case right? Nothing is really stored as a `.txt` format worth altering.

Is there a method of escaping this? Here, no sanitization occurs giving users the ability to put room 101 into here: what are the attack vectors? Can they escape my `.txt` force?

I understand they could create the malicious code here then potentially use a separate vulnerability to inject it directly from the file. I want to understand more about concatenation and the security vector behind it.

FYI: This is not best-practice and would never be in production. I just want conceptual understanding of what possibilities really lie here.

I've been testing it locally and trying to use the `PHP Strings` documentation to escape it within my user input. Ideally, I'm testing if I can create a PHP file on the server.

This was heavily inspired by the understanding of how user input can escape SQL queries using a comment like `--`.

Comment: I don't see how that hardcoded extension could be bypassed. It is perfectly allowed to have points in the filename, so `file.exe.xls.whatever.txt` is still a `.txt` file. The parallel you draw with SQL injection doesn't apply here. For that to work, PHP code would have to be interpreted twice; the first time to interpret the value of the variable and then a second time to interpret a character from that input as the beginning of a comment.

Comment: But of course the was site user account would not have access to snything outside of the document root would it :)

Comment: See also [PHP q&a on Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+filename).

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is true, although I have seen multiple servers running 777 permissions or even root because they containerise their applications incorrectly

Comment: @El_Vanja yeah, the suspected SQL remark was really just to summarise my point, not really to say one could do such a thing. I guess here the only real attack vector would be a chained attack, where a trusted file could potentially hold some real malicious code ready for a future vulnerability.

Comment: See also [null-byte character in filename](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/45958)

Comment: @Syscall ironically, my first though of `fopen` was it must be an arbitrary syscall because it deals with I/O but really, this part doesn't as its only generating the stream so nothing can be injected here. Thanks for these links, the `null-byte` like the post says, PHP prevents by default so its not something to worry about I suppose

Comment: @Syscall I have seen a few things like how a txt file and a rar file can have the a txt extension but when opened execute in different ways. [See more here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12955/multiple-extension-vulnerability-is-this-malicious-file-triggered-during-form-p) but again, this would be a chained attack not specifically what I'm asking here.

Comment: I think the question is meaningless, because by excluding "chained attacks", you exclude pretty much *all* attacks. Writing to `/etc/passwd` or `.ssh/authorized_keys` (which is used for _inbound_ connections; much more significant than `.ssh/id_rsa`, used for _outbound_ connections) is only dangerous because of what it allows the attacker to do _next_. Even SQL injection is likely to be used as part of a larger attack, e.g. create yourself an account, log in with it, do something else.

Comment: @IMSoP excluding chained attacks simply because my actual question here is only: "can you escape strings in PHP via input data?" - I'm well aware of what an attacker would do with the ability to write to any file - specially with the `a` flag being able to create unique files to later execute them or use them to bypass

Comment: But then the question is kind of pointless, surely? Either the answer is "no, but this isn't safe anyway", or it's "yes, and this isn't safe anyway".

Comment: @IMSoP True, perhaps I should remove this point about chained attacks? Perhaps people can then expand on the question in their answers?

Comment: Even if you can't create arbitrary file names with this, if there's some bug in *another* system, that may be good enough. Say that the SSH daemon has a bug in which it will try to read `.ssh/authorized_keys\x0.txt` because… reasons… well, that's a good enough attack vector.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking into whether or not, even though PHP parses null byte chars, do other languages automatically do it? & the short answer was no, but the long answer was it depends on what software the client has running on their system and where best to encapsulate the file - ie, using `glob` in php. Its a really interesting field, everyone (i'd hope) understands SQL, XSS, CSRF, XXE etc.. but what about genuine "mistakes", that seem relatively "safe" mistakes?  @deceze